# Is every Pre-Hilbert space reflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Good day,

It is known that every Hilbert space is reflexive. Does the same hold true for Pre-Hilbert spaces? I guess not since completeness is a pretty strong property that is now missing and the classical proof (as a corollary by Riesz) shouldn't work anymore. What do you think?

So if they are not reflexive could you give me an example of an non-reflexive Pre-Hilbert space?

Thanks a lot,
Marvin

Comment: No, if a pre-hilbert space is not complete it is not reflexive, dual spaces are always complete! On the other hand if a pre-hilbert space is complete, it is a hilbert space.

Comment: @s.harp Ah, right, thanks, I forgot that every reflexive normed vector space is automatically complete. So every Pre-Hilbert space that is not complete is therefore not reflexive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if a pre-Hilbert space is not complete it is not reflexive, dual spaces are always complete! On the other hand if a pre-Hilbert space is complete, it is a Hilbert space.